# Why the tab change to space in vim?

Tags: vim

```
>--->--->---<td class='size_rdo'><?php echo Form::radio('radio_size', $size_type->id.'|'.$siz>id); ?></td>
```

I put the cursor at `'Form'` and use `C` to delete to the line end.and complete this line with `?>`.at this point, the tab before this line change to space. 
Why this happened?

Comment: vim might be configured to automatically convert tabs to spaces. you can read about this here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces (I expect you want `set noexpandtab`)

Answer (score 1):

For html files a `>` character is one of the characters which causes reindentation of the current line (see [`indentkeys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentkeys%27) option). And with [`expandtab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27expandtab%27) option enabled, as Hemmer pointed out, spaces are used instead of tabs.